# Organize Js project files

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am at a point into developing an html5 game (sailing towards 500 lines in my main.js) where I'd need to split the code in several parts. I have already grouped different vars and functions by pertinence and moved these blocks into, for instance, main.js - game.js - player.js - enemy.js, ecc... and made them execute in the right order from html as to 'recompose' the main file I am working on now, like it was before splitting it:

```
<script src="main.js"></script> 
<script src="game.js"></script>  
<script src="player.js"></script>  
<script src="enemy.js"></script>
```

It would work fine but this way all the variables are be accessible from the console. I tried to wrap each individual script into a self-executing function to prevent this (as is my main.js at the moment), but this approach would make variables I need to be globally accessible to fall out of scope. So what's the best practice in this case? I am reading around a lot but every solution i find seems to be behind my js skills or too abstract for such a small project like mine. Could someone point at the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: By self-executing function, do you mean IIFEs? Just for clarification...

Comment: Akshat Mahajan yes I mean IIFEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are struggling with the question: `How should I modularize my app?`

Instead of defining each dependency of your app in html:

```
<script src="main.js"></script> 
<script src="game.js"></script>  
<script src="player.js"></script>  
<script src="enemy.js"></script>
```

It would be better to bundle your code with [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), or some other module bundler. That way you wouldn't need to concern yourself on the ordering of `<script>` tags.

You would then be able to include one `<script>` tag in your html:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Where `bundle.js` is the file containing your entire app code and any third party dependencies you may have used. Generating `bundle.js` could be achieved by using a module bundler as mentioned above.

Depending on your chosen module bundler's support, you can opt in to use modules of types such as CommonJS, AMD, ES6, etc. By establishing `modules` in your code, you will be able to export objects, functions, etc, and not pollute the global namespace. Thereby leading you to decouple your app from one giant file.

Comment: Thanks Christian. That's the question I'm struggling with... So the principle of module bounders would be just to separate my main.js into chunks of code to be put in separate files and still working as one block? Should this approach be used also during production or is it something to be done at the completion of the project?

Comment: Yes, a module bundler will help you separate your `main.js` into chunks that can live in different files.

Comment: This approach can be used not only in production, but also in development. However, in production you would take an extra step from concatenation and minify/uglify the bundled file as well to obfuscate and decrease file size. 

You might wonder how you will be able to debug or view errors when all the code is in one file. Source maps can help with that by giving useful references to the line number and original file name. They can be generated by module bundlers or other build tools.

Comment: Thanks! Seems I need to learn to use another tool I guess... Any pointer to some complete guide on the subject and the best product you would use in this case...? Thanks Again!

Comment: I would suggest to read http://blog.cloudfour.com/module_bunders_part_1/ for an introduction on modules in JavaScript. Also refer to https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/the-mind-boggling-universe-of-javascript-modules for some more comprehensive examples.

I think the front-runners for module bundling these days would either be Browserify or Webpack. I personally use Webpack which has been said to be somewhat more complicated to use, but provides more power and flexibility. I don't have any opinion about Browserify, but I've read it's a reliable option as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!